# React: TypeError: dispatch is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I want to fetch from redux. I am following this tutorial: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-application-hewdb?file=/src/pages/PostsPage.js

But when i used it in my code that is:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {fetchInterview} from '../actions/interviewActions'

const DetailInterview = (props, { dispatch, loading, interviews, hasErrors }) => {

  console.log("test interview",interviews)
  useEffect(() => {
    const { match: { params: { id } } } = props;
    dispatch(fetchInterview(id))
  }, [dispatch])

  const interviewslist = interviews

  console.log('interview: ', interviews)

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>All participants</h3>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Interview id</th>
            <th>Partcipants id</th>
            <th>Time</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {
            console.log('interviews:sad ', interviews)
          }
          {
            interviews? interviews.map((interview) => {
              console.log('sadassad',interview)
              console.log('sadaghahhgsghssad',interviews)
              return (
                <tr key={interview.id}>
                  <td>{interview.id}</td>
                  <td>{interview.interview_id}</td>
                  <td>
                    {/* <Link to={`/posts/${post.id}`}> */}
                    {interview.participant_id}
                    {/* </Link> */}
                  </td>
                  <td>{interview.created_at}</td>
                </tr>
              ) 
            }) : null
          }
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

// export default DetailInterview;

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  loading: state.interview.loading,
  interviews: state.interview.interview,
  hasErrors: state.interview.hasErrors,
})
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(DetailInterview)
```

I get an error: Uncaught TypeError: dispatch is not a function

Could not understand what is the error behind this.

Comment: React component has 1 argument props (`const DetailInterview = (props) => `), i.e. call `props.dispatch`

Comment: @NikitaMadeev But I also need props as it is need here: `const { match: { params: { id } } } = props;`

Comment: I do not propose to remove it, just the second argument the component does not have, call dispatch from props, example: `const { dispatch } = props;`

Comment: @NikitaMadeev values inside mapStateToProps are not storing.

Comment: they also come in `props`, just like `dispatch`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are destructuring values from the second argument of DetailInterview whereas you should do that from props as values from mapStateToProps and connect are available as props to the connected component

```
const DetailInterview = (props) => {
    const { dispatch, loading, interviews, hasErrors } = props;
    ...
}
```